# Skaffold update files but the app still use the start Dcoker image

Tags: php, kubernetes, k3s, skaffold

I'm having a local cluster using [K3d](https://k3s.io/), inside it, there is an API developed in Lumen (Laravel).

I'm also having [Skaffold](https://skaffold.dev/) to work and test my application inside my local cluster. I'm running Skaffold in dev mode, that will allow me to hot load my files in case of changes.

In my case the files did change inside the container but the app still act as the first pod creation. So I  can change file any time the app still have the same state always.

Here is my Skaffold deploy config

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta29
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: api
build:
  tagPolicy:
    sha256: {}
  artifacts:
    - image: api
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: '**/*'
            dest: '/var/www/html'
deploy:
  kustomize:
    paths:
      - k8s\dev
profiles:
  - name: base
    deploy:
      kustomize:
        paths:
          - k8s\base
```

Answer (score 0):

Skaffold's sync only transfers your files: you need to ensure your app or server then uses those changed files.

Some web frameworks are able detect and reload source changes (may require running in a *debug* mode).  Other approaches are to use separate tools to monitor for filesystem changes and relaunch the application; [`nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) and [`watchexec`](https://github.com/watchexec/watchexec) are some typical examples.

If you're syncing data files, you need to ensure that your code reloads file content, and doesn't continue using stale data.

Comment: do you have an example you can share using either nodemon or watchexec?